# My computer recognizes only one SATA disk

Tags: hard-drive, sata

I ran into a disk crash (system doesn't start) but data is available. it was a 2TB WD green. So I bought another one and installed Windows 8 on it, but the system only sees the new one.

I started the computer with the other disk and it recognizes it and attempts to start but only until the user log. So the data is still available.

Why cant I get the two disks working?

I think SATA drives doesn't need slave jumping or am I wrong?

Comment: It is possible that your old drive has failed.  Try to test the drive using WD Data Lifeguard Diagnostics for DOS.  http://products.wdc.com/support/kb.ashx?id=DbmQlF If WD DLG cannot detect your old HDD it's probably failed, or not getting enough power.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, satas don't need jumping (and they can't be). Maybe you had to check if,they are visible in the bios. In your case I think, your old hard drive has some hardware problem, which makes its data to be backed up as fast as you can.

Another possibioity, which in such cases happens very often, that you have some power problem. In your place I surely tried to remove every possible power consumer and tried again.

Or, in case of a contact problem, some tries to plug this into another sata connector in your mainboard were maybe helpful anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You are quite right that SATA disks do not need any jumpers set. There is no slave/master relation on SATA, as each drive is on its own cable.

You should try and enter the BIOS setup to check, if both disks are recognized in BIOS. This will help you identify the problem.

It is possible, that your first disk is simply malfunctioning or has had an error on the boot sector (i.e. corrupted MBR)

You can try the following method to repair a corrupted MBR:

[link to source guide, which includes pictures](http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/20864-mbr-restore-windows-7-master-boot-record.html)

1. Boot your computer to the Windows 7 DVD (or to a "Repair CD"). At this screen choose to install now.
2. Select your language and click next.
3. Click the button for "Use recovery tools".
4. Then select "Command Prompt".
5. When open, the command prompt will look like this:
6. The command we will use, `bootsect.exe`, is in a folder (named boot) on the DVD.
   We need to know what drive letter has been assigned the DVD drive to access the folder.

Type: `diskpart` and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>

Type: `select disk 0` and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>

Type: `list volume` and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>

7. Use your DVD drive letter and type: `exit` and press <kbd>Enter</kbd> to close Diskpart

Type: `G:` (use the letter of your DVD drive) and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>

Type: `cd boot` and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>

Type: `dir` and press <kbd>Enter</kbd> to verify that bootcect.exe is there (if you really need to)

8. To restore the "bootsector code":

Type: `bootsect /nt60 SYS /mbr` and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>

NOTE: If this method fails to restore the MBR, you can try the `bootrec` command as it is also a tool for repairing the MBR.

9. When completed successfully,

Type: `exit` and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>

This will close the command prompt window.

10. Now select Shut Down or Restart
11. Then you can reboot your computer into Windows.